# choosing page by using dax in powebi

Tags: powerbi, dax, power-bi-report-server

I make 2 page for night and day in Power bi, I want by passing time in the night background go dark and in the day background back to white , I Don't know how choose page with Dax Code ? Thanks friends

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Power BI doesn't support this feature.

Comment: Isn't any other way ? By using button and make a condition for it to where navigate?

Comment: Of cause you can use a bookmark button but then what's the difference to clicking the page tab?